# nested escaping regarding _e() function

Tags: php, wordpress, escaping, translation

first question ever here on stackoverflow: i want to escape html inside php AND then inside html php again AND return a string from an _e() function. i am not sure if the "lingo" is correct. so here is the case:

```
return '...<span class="strike"></span><a class="read-more" href="'. 
get_permalink($post->ID) . '" title="'.get_the_title($post->ID).'">Read more</a>';
```

the "read more" should be replaced with

```
_e( 'Read more', 'mytheme' )
```

to be able to translate the term.

I tried everything. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
return '...<span class="strike"></span><a class="read-more" href="'. 
get_permalink($post->ID) . '" title="'.get_the_title($post->ID).'">'._e( 'Read more', 'mytheme' ).'</a>';
```

Comment: You might want to call `htmlspecialchars ()` on the result of `_e()` to escape the HTML within the string.

Comment: hey tom, thank you very much. but unfortunately the link character of the phrase (to be translated) gets lost in this version.